# vba select current range but not with #N/A

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range that is a time and a number like this where "time" is in cell A1:

```
   time    number
   07:52:55  3
   07:53:52  2
   07:54:55  #N/A
   07:55:52  2
```

Now I want to select the range so I do:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
```

and this gives me the range above in the RNG object BUT i do not want any #N/A's.  Is there an easy way to get that range int RNG object without having #N/As.  I'd like to do this WITHOUT looping though the range. Is this possible? Can you use specialcells...?

I should say that I to read this range WIHOUT NAs into a 2D array. When I try to do filter the NAs using autofilter the "Arr" is not fully populated.

```
          Sheets("data").Select
                     Range("A1").Select
                     rngAddress = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
                     Selection.AutoFilter
                     ActiveSheet.Range(rngAddress).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>#N/A", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                      Range(rngAddress).Select
                     Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                     rng.Select
                     Arr = rng  'Arr is not populated with the full array
```

Thank you!

Comment: why not apply a filter and select only the visible cells?

Comment: The problem with that is that I have to read this into a 2D array and when I do this:     Range("A1").Select
                    rngAddress = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
                    Selection.AutoFilter
                    ActiveSheet.Range(rngAddress).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>#N/A", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                    Range(rngAddress).Select
                    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    rng.Select
                    Arr = rng

Answer (score 1):

I would personally do something like:

- .Sort the range by 'number' column descending (i believe the N/As will appear at the bottom)

  - use .Find to find the first NA
  - Select from Activecell.Row - 1

-Or-

If you dont care about keeping the N/As you can use:

```
Sub FormatSheet()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(Range("K6"), Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7))
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code will remove any rows that have an N/A

Code taken from: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/79525-how-detect-n-using-visual-basic-applications.html